# Display a progress bar while we wait for a process to return

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330834/4889267) and I'd like to implement the progress bar while I wait for a process to run - or in my case - many.

I'm running multiple copies of large filesystems in parallel using the following snippet

```bsh
for svol in "${svols[@]}";
do
    syslog_info "copying $svol"
    ${CP} -p $svol $somedir &
done
syslog_info "Parallel copy ongoing..."
wait
```

and I'm looking to add in the progress bar to display whilst I wait for the processes in the background to return..

This is my attempt, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or help to get it working?

```bsh
for svol in "${svols[@]}";
do
    syslog_info "copying $svol"
    ${CP} -p $svol $somedir &
done
syslog_info "Parallel copy ongoing..."

i=1
sp="/-\|"
echo -n ' '

until wait;
do
    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    sleep 0.1
done
```

EDIT: I've updated the original code in this question to a tested working solution - still trying to get it to run until the wait returns

As a side not - the original code at the top works fine as it is and the following snippet also works as a standalone piece of code

```bsh
i=1
sp="/-\|"
echo -n ' '

for i in {1..100};
do
    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Comment: Why did you use the nix tag? Did you read its description? Nix is a package manager. The nix tag does not stand for *NIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait` blocks until all the background jobs have returned so you can't use it as the `until` condition as it will run only once.

You could use `[ -n "$(jobs)" ]` instead to see if you have jobs running:

```
while [ -n "$(jobs)" ]; do
  printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
  sleep 0.1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux, you can use [the *Coreutils Progress Viewer* (`progress`, formerly know as `cv`)](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress):

```
"${CP}" -p -- "$svol" "$somedir" & progress -mp "$!"
```